# I've developed a derivative-free optimization method, looking for comments

Tags: optimization, c++, c, libraries

Here is the URL: https://github.com/avaneev/biteopt

I've tested it on numerous global optimization benchmarking functions (included), and on real-world hyperparameter optimization problems I have. Seems to be working quite well except in comparison to deterministic methods it's necessary to make several attempts at different random seeds, so the iteration budget may be high. But stochasticity of this method gives a chance to solve a problem which can't be sufficiently solved by deterministic methods. Anyway, most benchmarking functions solve in 1 attempt given enough iteration budget.

Works best for non-convex problems, and can also solve convex problems, but of course slower than deterministic methods. Can also solve non-linear constrained problems, but such constraints increase convergence time considerably (though, this application was not tested thoroughly).

Still working on the method.

I would like to hear comments from users that have some practical models (e.g. black-box hyperparameter optimization) which are still needed to be solved acceptably - whether this method works or not for their models, possibly with the description of the model.

Here is the description of the method. The algorithm consists of the following elements:

1. A cost-ordered population of previous solutions is maintained. A solution is an independent parameter vector which is evolved towards a better solution. On every iteration, the best solution is evolved.
   $$x_\text{new}=x_\text{best}$$
   Below, *i* is either equal to rand(1, N) or in the range [1; N], depending on the `AllpProb` probability. Probabilities are defined in the range [0; 1] and in many instances in the code were replaced with simple resetting counters for more efficiency. Parameter values are internally normalized to [0; 1] range and, to stay in this range, are wrapped in a special manner before each function evaluation. Algorithm's hyper-parameters (probabilities) were pre-selected and should not be changed.
2. Depending on the `RandProb` probability, a single (or all) parameter value randomization is performed using "bitmask inversion" operation.
   $$mask= 2^{1+\lfloor(0.999999997-rand(0\ldots1)^4 )\cdot MantSize\rfloor}-1$$
   $$MantMult=2^{MantSize}$$
   $$x_\text{new}[i] = \frac{\lfloor x_\text{new}[i]\cdot MantMult \rfloor \bigotimes mask }{MantMult}$$
   Plus, with `CentProb` probability the random "step in the right direction" operation is performed using the centroid vector, twice.
   $$m_1=\text{rand}(0\ldots1)\cdot CentSpan$$
   $$x_\text{new}[i]=x_\text{new}[i]-m_1(x_\text{new}[i]-x_\text{cent}[i])$$
   $$m_2=\text{rand}(0\ldots1)\cdot CentSpan$$
   $$x_\text{new}[i]=x_\text{new}[i]-m_2(x_\text{new}[i]-x_\text{cent}[i])$$
   With `RandProb2` probability an alternative randomization method is used.
   $$x_\text{new}[i]=x_\text{new}[i]+(-1)^{s}(x_\text{cent}[i]-x_\text{new}[i]), \quad i=1,\ldots,N,\\ \quad s\in\{1,2\}=(\text{rand}(0\ldots1)<0.5 ? 1:2)$$
3. (Not together with N.2) the "step in the right direction" operation is performed using the random previous solution, current best and worst solutions. This is conceptually similar to Differential Evolution's "mutation" operation.
   $$x_\text{new}=x_\text{best}-\frac{(x_\text{worst}-x_\text{rand})}{2}$$
4. With `ScutProb` probability a "short-cut" parameter vector change operation is performed.
   $$z=x_\text{new}[\text{rand}(1,N)]$$
   $$x_\text{new}[i]=z, \quad i=1,\ldots,N$$
5. After each objective function evaluation, the highest-cost previous solution is replaced using the cost constraint.

You can find this algorithm implemented in the `optimize()` function in `biteopt.h` on lines 284-395, it does not involve any higher-order math.

Comment: While this might be an interesting method, the post does not feature any technical detail about it. The mentioned GitHub page contains more; however, I still do not see a clean mathematical description of what is happening inside. I would recommend including the necessary technical details to this post, as well as a more concrete question because a request for comments is not aligned well with how CompSci SE works.

Comment: This question could arguably be more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you were just looking for comments about the code quality and structure. If you were to, say, post an example problem here and some benchmarks of how your code does, others might be able to offer some feedback on how it stacks up against other methods or implementations.

Comment: I'm 20 years in commercial software production, no need for code review. But I do need a review of the optimization method itself, and that can only be done by users/specialists in optimization field, not by programmers.

Comment: _I'm 20 years in commercial software production, no need for code review_. I disagree - code review is always useful, even for seasoned programmers

Comment: Maybe code review is useful, but I think the chance to meet a person that can do a quality code review for free is minimal. Meanwhile, I've updated my question with method description and some maths.

Comment: @aleksv *But I do need a review of the optimization method itself, and that can only be done by users/specialists in optimization field, not by programmers.* Then you should write it up and submit it for publication to a specialized academic journal -- that's exactly how peer review works.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianClason. While the quality of the post **improved significantly**, it is still unclear what is/are your particular question/s. You definitely have an option of a peer review in some reputable academic journal or you may rephrase your post to include specific questions.

Comment: Well, maybe some people here have some models which were solved unacceptably, so they may try the method and give comments, whether results will be bad or not. I can run synthetic benchmarks in abundance, and make comparisons to other methods (which I've already did approximately), but I need comments from real users, not just a peer review on quality of the material submitted to a journal.

Comment: I think it is not so helpful to advise writing up as a scientific paper. Other than altruism for the scientific community this has little value outside academia. The author is asking for a bit of advice and input on the method is this causal forum. I have asked many questions here before on mathematical methods and never encountered this disappointing attitudes. Personally I think this question poses a reasonable request and is appropriate for this site provided the post includes sufficient technical information on the method.

Comment: @boyfarrell Yes, but you have asked *specific* questions on mathematical methods, which is definitely appropriate for this site. On the other hand, "Here's my method, discuss" is *not* what this site is for -- for one thing, it requires significantly more time investment than is reasonable (again) for this site. Peer reviewing of an academic write-up is a much closer approximation of what is wanted here.

Comment: To put it briefly, there needs to be some parity between the amount of effort put into addressing an audience (whether it be users of this site or peer reviewers for a journal) and the amount of effort on your behalf you can expect from them in return. And my feeling is that this is missing here (but not in @boyfarrell's questions, for example). It is even worse if -- as it seems from aleksv' comment -- you are looking for *commercial* evaluation, where you are asking others to do part of the work (market assessment) for free...

Comment: People invest a lot of time into studying and using optimization methods to suit their models. If you do not need it, no problem, why negative attitude? StackExchange destroyed forums, all people in the fields are on StackExchange, so it's a bit embarrasing to hear I can't ask for comments on my method, because usual forums are essentially dead.

Comment: Also, what "market assessment"? This is a free open-source code. I receive nothing of value, I'm not even receiving funding like full-time scientists do. My method is basically the same story as Nelder-Mead code in Numerical Recipes. Consdering the negative response I've got here, I guess Nelder&Mead would have a lot of problem telling about their method if they released it nowadays.

Comment: @boyfarrell, by definition this site is not a forum. The format of this site is Question and Answers, and that's why this "question" has created such reactions.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to hear comments from users that have some practical models (e.g. black-box hyperparameter optimization) which are still needed to be solved acceptably - whether this method works or not for their models, possibly with the description of the model.

Looks like you want somebody to invest what may be considerable time and energy in trying out your new method on their models, *and* report on the results.

As a modeler, I have to ask myself the question: *why* would I do that? It'd take me some time to change my code and link in your method. *What* does your optimization method have to offer that may be better than my current method of choice? Now, we can't possibly answer this question because (a) you don't know what models I'm working with, and (b) I don't know what kind of problems your method is good for - beyond some "real-life optimization problems" where it "seems to be working quite well".

Bottom line is you have to do a heck of a better job "selling" your method to the community at large. You could start by:

- testing the method on a representative sample of problems where you expect it to do well, and report on the results;
- compare the results with those achieved by similar, known methods (to show us that you're at least competitive with the state of the art);
- show that your method converges, and under which conditions - if you can't come up with a formal proof, then at least give some heuristic arguments (backed up by some solid experimental data);
- advise on the choice of hyper-parameters, like `RandProb`, `CentProb`, etc.
- tell us what problems we should *not* be using your method on, and why.

Comment: ...which is a pretty good description of a typical publication in the field of optimization :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Optimization field is sparse. Will you buy someone's own benchmarks? I would not, I've studied optimization enough to not believe in "published results" since they are in most cases biased. Then my problems of choice are not your problems of choice. It would be more useful if you actually included problems you are interested in solving, I may check them out. Not sure I understand your notion of "investing a lot of time". The example provided is as simple as it can be, only 5 minutes of time to download, study and print "gcc example.cpp".

Comment: I did comparisons and included results on the project page - but as I've expected, you are not buying it. What can I do more?

Comment: Hyperparameters should not be changed. I've mentioned problems my method should not be used on - problems with multiple minima without detectable global descent (Bukin 6), problems with rogue optimums (Damavandi), combinatorial problems (Lennard-Jones and Perm problems).

Comment: @ChristianClason unless the OP is working for some institution I think it is _entirely unreasonable_ to expect them to approach any publication individually!